# Can we copy the value of one field to another in a repeating table of infopath form?

Tags: infopath, repeat

Hi guys can anyone tell me how to copy a field value in a repeating table to another field when we insert another row. It is just like amazon checkout process. In Amazon checkout process we have to click a check box when our billing address is same as our shipping address.

In this scenario am having one text box and drop down box fields in a repeating table. When am writing something in the text box and inserting another row. here come the problem I have inserted a value in the drop down box, when the value is selected in the drop down box the textbox value from the parent should be copied to the child node. This has to be done without any code behind.

Please help me regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this using the default value of the child node.

The default value can reference another field either on your main datasource or any secondary datasource.

I would assume that you don't want this updating when the user adds another child node. If that is the case then you will need to uncheck the "Update this value when the value of the foumlua is recalculated."